# Saving changes to a dropdown box into a database in CakePHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, cakephp

I am new to cake and mysql, and am trying to create a simple job tracking app.  I want to have a dropdown box for each job with a list of the status' a job can be at.  When a user changes the active item in the box I want to save this into the database.

Any help in how to handle this would be very much appreciated.  Below is what I have tried so far:

How I create the set of forms in the view with the options taken from the enums in my database table:

```
<?php $id = count($jobs)-1; ?>
<?php for ($job = count($jobs)-1; $job >= 0; --$job): ?>
<tr>
<td>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('status'.(string)$id, array('type'=>'select', 'class' => 'statusSelect','label'=>'', 'options'=>$states, 'default'=>$jobs[$job]['Job']['Status'])); ?>
</td>
```

I am using a jquery script to set an on change listener for each dropdown and call an action in my controller:

```
$(".statusSelect").change(function(){
//Grab job number from the id of select box
    var jobNo = parseInt($(this).attr('id').substring(6));
var value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'http://localhost/projectManager/jobs',
        data:{  'id': jobNo,
            'status':value}, 
            success : function(data) {
               alert(jobNo);// this alert works
            },
        error : function() {
           //alert("false");
        }
    });

});
```

And I have this function in my controller:

```
public function changeState($id = null, $status = null) {
    //I don't think the id and status are actually 
        //being placed as arguments to this function
        //from my js script
}
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

You are POSTing to `/projectManager/jobs`, which corresponds to `ProjectManagerController::jobs()`.

Your function is declared as `public function changeState($id = null, $status = null)`. Assuming `changeState(..)` is a function within `ProjectManagerController`, this corresponds to `/projectManager/changeState/$id/$status`.

You need to switch the URL the AJAX is POSTing to. You can either do something like:

`url:'http://localhost/projectManager/changeState/'+jobNo+'/'+value'`, remove the `data {}`  and leave your function as is, or you can do

`url:'http://localhost/projectManager/changeState'`, leave the `data {}`, change your function to `changeState()` and then use `$this->request->data` within `changeState()` to access the data.

I am guessing you have another function, `jobs()`, and that is why the AJAX is working properly and the `alert` is generating.